# Skipping a line when it doesn't have the correct name with the scanner class

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner, skip

```
public void populateFromFile(String filename)
{
    
    try
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        
        //variables
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String emailAddress;
        String startYear;
        String startMonth;
        String clubName;
        Member tmp;
        
    
        //skip first line
        sc.nextLine();
        sc.useDelimiter(";");
        sc.skip(
        while (sc.hasNext())
        {
            sc.next();
            firstName = sc.next();
            lastName = sc.next();
            emailAddress = sc.next();
            startYear = sc.next();
            int year = Integer.parseInt(startYear);
            startMonth = sc.next();
            int month = Integer.parseInt(startMonth);
            clubName = sc.next();
            tmp = new Member(firstName,lastName,emailAddress,month,year);
            if(clubName == name)
            {
                addMember(tmp);
            }

        }
        sc.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    };
}
```

> I'm trying to find a way how I only can add the 'Members' who are from the correct club. But when I am trying to put an if statement in the while loop the program runs forever. Do you have any other idea how I could do this?

Comment: You use `.equals()` to compare strings and not `==`.

Comment: You can also use `sc.nextInt` instead of converting scanned strings to int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example I created based on your problem.  This should solve your problem.

```
        String str = "x;a1;b1;c1;d1\ny;a2;b2;c2;d2\nx;a3;b3;c3;d4";
        Scanner s = new Scanner(str);
        
        while(s.hasNextLine()){
            Scanner s2 = new Scanner(s.nextLine());
            s2.useDelimiter(";");
            String h = s2.next();
            String a = s2.next();
            String b = s2.next();
            String c = s2.next();
            String d = s2.next();
            
            if (h.equals("x")){
                System.out.printf("%s|%s|%s|%s\n", a,b,c,d);
            }
        }
```

The output is:

```
a1|b1|c1|d1
a3|b3|c3|d3
```